# How to generate a very secure wallet with Electrum?

Tags: private-key, electrum, wallet-security, coldstorage, recover-private-key

For a poor-mans [glacier](https://glacierprotocol.org/docs/before-you-start/overview/) protocol, looking for:

```
One private key – an alphanumeric string used to secure the funds
The cold storage address – an alphanumeric string designating the virtual “location” of the funds
The “redemption script” – an additional code needed to access funds, shared by all private keys.
```

but can I accomplish something *similar* with the Electrum wallet?  Based on IRC discussions, I've been pointed to `libsecp256k1` for [generating](https://www.reddit.com/r/Electrum/comments/9testg/getting_libsecp256k1_to_work_with_electrum_wallet/) the keys.

see also:

https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum-docs/blob/master/libsecp256k1-linux.rst

Where I get stuck is with the what, precisely, to write down and what medium to use.  Because writing down a private key in its entirety seems a questionable endeavor, at best.  so, it's a matter of noting the "words" used to deterministically re-generate the private key?

---

In that context, how do I use `electrum` to [generate a wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/99947/111738) approaching the security provided by something like the `glacier` protocol?  Assuming all else is equal, particularly with regards to quarantined hardware et. al.

---

additional context:

> There are two types of digital wallets: hot wallets and cold wallets.
> Hot wallets are connected to the internet while cold wallets are not.
> Most digital wallet holders hold both a hot wallet and a cold wallet.
> Hot wallets are most often used to make quick payments, while a cold
> wallet is generally used for storing and holding your money, and has
> no connection to the internet.[citation needed] Another difference
> that is apparent when comparing the types of digital wallets, or
> e-Wallets, is the price. While most hot wallets are free, cold wallets
> can be expensive.[citation needed]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_wallet#Types

Comment: the seed can be written down as a paper wallet.  the seed can then be used to generate the private key, and the private key to generate the public key.  or so is my understanding.